# surface plot on irregular grid in python environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is it possible to create surface plot and contour plot of a function for example `u(x,y) = x^2 + y^2`

on following domain which is bounded by equation

```
r(t) = 1+(cos(4*t))^2, x = r(t)*cos(t),y = r(t)*sin(t), 0 < t < 2*pi
```

[image]

I want surface plot variant of following scatter plot.
[image]
 I also used scipy `griddata` as follows

```
from matplotlib.pyplot  import *
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

data = np.array([[ 2.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 1.89614525e+00,  1.51126793e-01],
   [ 1.62613327e+00,  2.60869688e-01],
   [ 1.29639187e+00,  3.15328472e-01],
   [ 1.03183519e+00,  3.39805963e-01],
   [ 9.22330309e-01,  3.87424263e-01],
   [ 9.85968247e-01,  5.09806830e-01],
   [ 1.16496791e+00,  7.25092951e-01],
   [ 1.35481653e+00,  1.00089121e+00],
   [ 1.45215333e+00,  1.26290100e+00],
   [ 1.39897768e+00,  1.42707450e+00],
   [ 1.20351374e+00,  1.44074409e+00],
   [ 9.29854857e-01,  1.31248166e+00],
   [ 6.63453200e-01,  1.11474417e+00],
   [ 4.70396020e-01,  9.55864325e-01],
   [ 3.70174853e-01,  9.32786757e-01],
   [ 3.33831717e-01,  1.08590518e+00],
   [ 3.06157327e-01,  1.37738581e+00],
   [ 2.38732323e-01,  1.70413196e+00],
   [ 1.15900227e-01,  1.94068353e+00],
   [-3.96388724e-02,  1.99329358e+00],
   [-1.83621616e-01,  1.84088591e+00],
   [-2.79344160e-01,  1.54430632e+00],
   [-3.22477316e-01,  1.21965478e+00],
   [-3.47231849e-01,  9.87829012e-01],
   [-4.09520279e-01,  9.23088740e-01],
   [-5.55288737e-01,  1.02352335e+00],
   [-7.90735832e-01,  1.21586141e+00],
   [-1.07111976e+00,  1.39113164e+00],
   [-1.31601256e+00,  1.45381050e+00],
   [-1.44544698e+00,  1.36169834e+00],
   [-1.42013085e+00,  1.13913085e+00],
   [-1.26561597e+00,  8.59376173e-01],
   [-1.06700598e+00,  6.06642746e-01],
   [-9.34540362e-01,  4.37040778e-01],
   [-9.54661396e-01,  3.57053472e-01],
   [-1.14896223e+00,  3.28361061e-01],
   [-1.46070082e+00,  2.94327457e-01],
   [-1.77632959e+00,  2.12929020e-01],
   [-1.97334870e+00,  7.85155418e-02],
   [-1.97334870e+00, -7.85155418e-02],
   [-1.77632959e+00, -2.12929020e-01],
   [-1.46070082e+00, -2.94327457e-01],
   [-1.14896223e+00, -3.28361061e-01],
   [-9.54661396e-01, -3.57053472e-01],
   [-9.34540362e-01, -4.37040778e-01],
   [-1.06700598e+00, -6.06642746e-01],
   [-1.26561597e+00, -8.59376173e-01],
   [-1.42013085e+00, -1.13913085e+00],
   [-1.44544698e+00, -1.36169834e+00],
   [-1.31601256e+00, -1.45381050e+00],
   [-1.07111976e+00, -1.39113164e+00],
   [-7.90735832e-01, -1.21586141e+00],
   [-5.55288737e-01, -1.02352335e+00],
   [-4.09520279e-01, -9.23088740e-01],
   [-3.47231849e-01, -9.87829012e-01],
   [-3.22477316e-01, -1.21965478e+00],
   [-2.79344160e-01, -1.54430632e+00],
   [-1.83621616e-01, -1.84088591e+00],
   [-3.96388724e-02, -1.99329358e+00],
   [ 1.15900227e-01, -1.94068353e+00],
   [ 2.38732323e-01, -1.70413196e+00],
   [ 3.06157327e-01, -1.37738581e+00],
   [ 3.33831717e-01, -1.08590518e+00],
   [ 3.70174853e-01, -9.32786757e-01],
   [ 4.70396020e-01, -9.55864325e-01],
   [ 6.63453200e-01, -1.11474417e+00],
   [ 9.29854857e-01, -1.31248166e+00],
   [ 1.20351374e+00, -1.44074409e+00],
   [ 1.39897768e+00, -1.42707450e+00],
   [ 1.45215333e+00, -1.26290100e+00],
   [ 1.35481653e+00, -1.00089121e+00],
   [ 1.16496791e+00, -7.25092951e-01],
   [ 9.85968247e-01, -5.09806830e-01],
   [ 9.22330309e-01, -3.87424263e-01],
   [ 1.03183519e+00, -3.39805963e-01],
   [ 1.29639187e+00, -3.15328472e-01],
   [ 1.62613327e+00, -2.60869688e-01],
   [ 1.89614525e+00, -1.51126793e-01],
   [ 2.00000000e+00, -4.89858720e-16],
   [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.50000000e+00],
   [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00],
   [ 1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00],
   [-5.00000000e-01, -5.00000000e-01],
   [ 0.00000000e+00, -5.00000000e-01],
   [ 5.00000000e-01, -5.00000000e-01],
   [-1.50000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-5.00000000e-01,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 5.00000000e-01,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 1.50000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [ 2.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-5.00000000e-01,  5.00000000e-01],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  5.00000000e-01],
   [ 5.00000000e-01,  5.00000000e-01],
   [-1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
   [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.50000000e+00]])   
ua = data[:,0]**2+data[:,1]**2 # u=x^2+y^2


xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,100),np.linspace(-2,2,100))
Ua = griddata((data[:,0],data[:,1]),ua,(xx,yy),method='cubic') 

fig = figure(1)
plot (data[:,0], data[:,1], '*'); # 
fig = figure(2)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(xx,yy,Ua,rstride=1,cstride=1,linewidth=.5)
```

but the result is not good as below
[image]

Comment: What code did you use to create the second plot? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @Joooeey: I added the codes. As i said i expect surface plot and contour plot for given domain.

Comment: Okay. What's wrong with the result? Does it show the correct domain? It looks like the domain might be off.
Also, if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can just copy into my IDE, it will make it much easier to figure out what's going wrong. I. e., where's the code that defines `data`?

Comment: The one you show is a surface plot. You can get the contourplot with `contour(xx, yy, Ua)`.

Comment: I know it is a surface plot but it is not correct. (see scatter plot).

Comment: Okay, so the surface plot doesn't plot on the correct domain like I said. I found the reason: `scipy.interpolate.griddata` interpolates inside a convex hull. So it interpolates between your lobes too. Perhaps you need a different approach to make it work. I'll see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the function on a rectangular grid in the first place!

`scipy.interpolate.griddata` interpolates on a convex hull. You can read that in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). That means that it also interpolates between your lobes. That's why you don't get the correct domain. Interpolation is also inherently less accurate than just calculating the function across the grid.

`plot_wireframe` wants a rectangular grid which you already created. All you need to do is calculate the function values on the rectangular grid. To only plot values on your domain boundary, set everything outside it to `np.NaN` (not-a-number).

Here's how to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# cartesian coordinates
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,100),np.linspace(-2,2,100))

# function value across square domain
Ua = xx**2 + yy**2

# polar coordinates
tt = np.arctan2(yy, xx)
rr = np.sqrt(Ua) # re-using x^2 + y^2 -- only works for this function

# r coordinate of domain boundary
domain_boundary = 1 + (np.cos(4*tt))**2

# function value across actual domain, with rest set to NaN
Ua[rr > domain_boundary] = np.NaN

# plotting
fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(xx,yy,Ua,rstride=1,cstride=1,linewidth=.5)
```

[image]

That solution is not perfect as you can recognize the rectangular grid in the result. You could try working in polar coordinates as shown in [this official matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_radial.html).

Comment: Actually my Ua has not a formula like x^2+y^2 generally. What if my Ua could not be stated explicitly. Also the above codes are not working with plot_surface command.

Comment: 1. If Ua has a different formula, you just have to substitute `rr = np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2)` to get the radius coordinate. 2. As long as Ua is a function on a 2D domain, there should be a way to state it explicitly (i. e. to compute it from the x and y values). If it's not a function (i. e. if there are two z values for one xy pair), things get complicated. Best to ask a new question for that.

Comment: `ax.plot_surface` doesn't fail for me. The domain boundary just looks very rugged. You'll have to put a lot of thought into how to make your grid to make it look nice. You could also try `ax.plot_trisurf` (as suggesed in the deleted answer to your Q). Trisurf takes xx, yy and Ua as 1D arrays though.